# Ajax, content-type header and python

Tags: python, ajax, header

When using python for web as opposed to PHP, you have to manually write this header: `Content-type:text/html`.

If I want to change the inner HTML of an element with ajax, should my python script (requested by ajax) output the above header or just plain HTML as a response?

Comment: Uhm, what? You imply so many wrong statements in this question that I can't figure out what you really want. Let some code speak for you ...

Comment: +1 for the Alice in Chains cover.

Comment: @Jochen I'm sorry, I'm new to web development. Can you tell me exactly which statements were wrong?

Comment: @NewNumOrder If you're new to web development you might want to go over your questions a thousand times before asking them here. Otherwise, every question you ask will be down-voted into oblivion by the SO trolls.

Comment: @NewNumOrder I can't help you with that - I'm fairly new to ajax and a  newb at best when it comes to python. The "Uhm, What?" comment above just pissed me off - that's all. And I'm pretty sure he down-voted your question because it didn't meet his troll standards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every HTTP Response **must** include a Content-Type header. PHP happens to insert one by default. Whatever Python library you are using apparently doesn't. Therefore you need to provide one explicitly.

This leaves the question as "Should a fragment of HTML be served as text/html?"

The [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2854.txt) says:

> The text/html media type is now
>   defined by W3C Recommendations; the
>   latest published version is [HTML401].
>   In addition, [XHTML1] defines a
>   profile of use of XHTML which is
>   compatible with HTML
>   4.01 and which may also be labeled as text/html.

These specifications do not define HTML fragments, so you should probably use something like:

```
Content-Type: x-text/html-fragment
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. By library did you actually meant framework? It's just that I thought only frameworks do these things for you.

Comment: A framework is just a collection of libraries and some helper executables.

Comment: What I want to know is if there's any standard library that I should be using. I know there's 'os' which has environment variables and 'cgi' which can be used for get/post variables. I don't want to use any non-standard libraries except something for DB.